# Google Script to get Google Spreadsheet menu content?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to be able to hack one of the menus of Google Spreadsheet using Google script and get its content placed into a side-bar. Especially, I want to get the `Data > Filter views ...` content.

Is it at all possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it at all possible?

No - scripts can add custom menus or extend the add-on menu, but not otherwise modify the out-of-the-box UI.

Comment: The HtmlService 'sanitizes' all html before serving it, using the caja compiler. Much of your html gets re-written. Unsafe or unsupported tags and scripts get removed... including window references.